# Tabela temporária MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

Como atribuir um update em uma tabela temporaria no meu caso eu faço um update logo no inicio, crio uma tabela temporaria e logo em seguida uma trigger(gatilho) nesse gatilho tento atribuir os valores alterados pelo update a tabela temporaria e logo em seguida faço um select na tabela temporaria porém sempre vem vazio mesmo eu alterando um registro na tabela e executando o update

Código:

```
 MySqlCommand queryCommand = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE fl_produtos SET  ativo_adwords = '0' where produto_quantidade = @produtoQuantidade", conn);
                queryCommand.Parameters.Add("@produtoQuantidade", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                queryCommand.Parameters["@produtoQuantidade"].Value = 0;



               MySqlCommand queryCommand1 = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Produtos_Desativados AS (SELECT produto_nome, produto_quantidade, ativo_adwords, idfabricante FROM fl_produtos) ENGINE=MEMORY;", conn);

                MySqlCommand queryCommand2 = new MySqlCommand("DELIMITER CREATE TRIGGER Tgr_ProdutosDesativados_Update AFTER UPDATE ON fl_produtos FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO Produtos_Desativados SET ativo_adwords = OLD.ativo_adwords, produto_nome = OLD.produto_nome, idfabricante = OLD.idfabricante, produto_quantidade = OLD.produto_quantidade END; DELIMITER", conn);

                MySqlCommand queryCommand3 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT produto_nome, produto_quantidade, ativo_adwords, idfabricante FROM Produtos_Desativados", conn);
```

Comment: Você poderia explica melhor, não entendi do que você precisa.

Comment: Favor colocar os comandos na ordem em que estão sendo executados.

Comment: @Osvaldo não entendi o que você quis dizer?

Comment: @downvoter: Repetir o que você já escreveu, e não foi entendido, não vai adiantar de nada.

Comment: @downvoter: Por que com os comandos sendo executados na ordem apresentada não existia o gatilho (trigger) quando da execução do UPDATE e portanto não haveria como dispara-lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível criar triggers com tabelas temporárias.

Retirado do [manual do mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html)

> You cannot associate a trigger with a TEMPORARY table or a view.